# Numbers along a circle

Tags: combinatorics, logic

$2019$ numbers are placed along a circumference of a circle. When any five successive numbers are added, the total is always $70$. What are these $2019$ numbers? Find all possible answers.

Comment: Welcome to Math StackExchange. Please provide more context and show how you tried to solve the problem. Please check the "How to ask a good question" thread for more information. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: One obvious possibility is that all the numbers are $14$.  Can you find another?

Comment: @user687894 Show please your attempts. Give me a possibility to show to you my solution.

Comment: I of course realised the answer wherein all numbers are 14. Other ones include 4 numbers as 1 and the 5th as 66

Comment: You can also have 2,2,2,2,62

Comment: 3,3,3,3,58       4,4,4,4,54 etc.

Comment: What is the source of this problem? Since it includes the current year, one might suspect it is from an ongoing contest/exam.

Answer (score 4):

Let $a_k$ be the number on k-th place, starting from some arbitrary point. We have, for any $k$: $$ a_k + a_{k+1} + a_{k+2} + a_{k+3} + a_{k+4} = 70 $$
Where $a_{k}$ for $k>2019$ is defined as $a_k := a_{k-2019}$. In particular
$$ a_k + a_{k+1} + a_{k+2} + a_{k+3} + a_{k+4} = a_{k+1} + a_{k+2} + a_{k+3} + a_{k+4} + a_{k+5}$$
which means that for any $k$:
$$ a_k = a_{k+5} $$
and for any $n\in\mathbb Z$
$$ a_k = a_{k+5n}$$
This in particular means that $$a_{1}=a_{2021}=a_2 = a_{2022} = a_3 = a_{2023} = a_4 = a_{2024} = a_5$$
From this it follows that all $a_k$ need to be equal. So $a_k=14$ is the only solution.

Comment: The question doesn't state that the 2019 numbers are consecutive. Therefore, I do not understand why we would use ak+ak+1+ak+2+ak+3+ak+4=70

Comment: The question mentions successive rather than consecutive numbers

Comment: @user687894 I may be mistaken, but my dictionary lists successive and consecutive as synonyms. What's the difference?

Comment: I think the question refers to the numbers next to each other as successive (12,18,19,38) as opposed to consecutive (12,13,14,15)

Comment: Hence you would be able to use the numbers 1,1,1,1,66 since they are successive but not consecutive

Comment: To clarify, successive as in physically next to each other. Consecutive as in next to each in terms of an order

Comment: Here is a quora article which clarifies better.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-are-consecutive-numbers-and-successive-numbers

Comment: It seems to me that consecutive is a special case of successive. Consecutive numbers are also successive. Also, I believe when the question talks about successive numbers, it means their position, not their value. Thhough that would mean a problem with successivity on a circle, if successivity is considered to be more generla than consecutivity, because you don't have distinguished first and last elements. That would effectively mean that every five elements on a circle are successive.